# How to split array argument with whitespace using Perl's Getopt::ArgParse

Tags: perl

I'm attempting to write a parser that will accept whitespace as a split, but am failing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.036;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use autodie ':all';
use Getopt::ArgParse;

my $parser = Getopt::ArgParse->new_parser(
    help        => 'help menu', 
);
$parser-> add_args(
    ['-foo',    '-f', required => 1, type => 'Array', split => ' '],
#the above list gets output
#in: perl Getopt_ArgParse.pl -f a b c
#out: a

);

my $ns = $parser->parse_args(@ARGV);
say join ("\n", @{ $ns->foo });
```

However, when I run

```
perl Getopt_ArgParse.pl -f a b c
```

all I get is `a`

How can I write the script so that when I run `perl Getopt_ArgParse.pl -f a b c` to get 3 values for `-f`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no space in any of the arguments. (You are passing `@ARGV = ( "-f", "a", "b", "c" );`.) That suggests `split => ' '` is completely wrong for what you want to achieve.

So what would allow you to use that syntax? While Getopt::Long supports this syntax, I don't see anything in Getopt::ArgParse's documentation supporting it. Note that the lack of support of this syntax by Getopt::ArgParse might be intentional. `-f a b c` usually means `-f a -- b c`, so it's confusing, and one might accidentally use `-f a b c` thinking it means `-f a -- b c`.

So what syntax can you use instead? You can use `-f a -f b -f c` or `-f 'a b c'`. The latter requires `split => ' '` in addition to `type => 'Array'`, while the former works with or without it.

```perl
use v5.36;
use Getopt::ArgParse qw( );

my $parser = Getopt::ArgParse->new_parser();

$parser->add_args(
   [ '--foo', '-f', type => 'Array', split => ' ' ],
   [ '--bar', '-b', type => 'Array'               ],
   [ 'pos', nargs => '*' ],
);

my $ns = $parser->parse_args( @ARGV );
say for $ns->foo->@*;
say "--";
say for $ns->bar->@*;
say "--";
say for $ns->pos->@*;
```

```
$ perl a.pl -f a b c
a
--
--
b
c

$ perl a.pl -f a -f b -f c
a
b
c
--
--

$ perl a.pl -f 'a b c'
a
b
c
--
--

$ perl a.pl -b a -b b -b c
--
a
b
c
--

$ perl a.pl -b 'a b c'
--
a b c
--
```